# Remove NA in R to compute cumulative returns

Tags: r

I am trying to compute cumulative returns in R, using `cumprod()` for $1 invested

I seem to be getting NA values after using the `cumprod()` function, because the first return I'm trying to use is NA and therefore not successfully cumulating returns.

```
[1]           NA -0.059898142 -0.267314770 -0.075349437  0.008658063 -0.008658063  0.000000000
```

The first row is NA and because of that, the `cumprod(x+1)` function turns into all NAs

How do I remove the first row/ignore the NA?

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: You can remove the first value from vector `x[-1]` and remove the first row by `x[-1, ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative Returns with NA's in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574199/cumulative-returns-with-nas-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na.omit` to remove `NA` values in `x` before applying `cumprod`, e.g.,

```
cumprod(na.omit(x))
```